# Can you run a SEM on a correlation matrix only (without a covariance matrix)?

Tags: correlation, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I have access to correlations between my variables of interest and the overall sample size. But I don't have standard deviations so I can't construct a covariance matrix. Can I still run a SEM on the correlation matrix? E.g. using the "sem" function in lavaaan, and specifying the name of the correlation matrix in the "sample.cov" argument.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done but there are potential problems. See

Cudeck, R. (1989). Analysis of correlation matrices using covariance structure models. Psychological Bulletin, 105(2), 317–327. https://doi.org/10.1037/0033-2909.105.2.317

https://statpower.net/Content/319SEM/Reading/Cudeck89.pdf

Comment: And these problems can be overcome by specifying constraints consistent with analyzing a correlation matrix (i.e., constraining each endogenous variable's residual variances to be 1 minus its explained variance, thereby indirectly constraining the total variance to be 1).